# How can I read in a list of tuples from a .csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a `.csv` file wherein one column has observations that look like the following:

`csv["tuplist"][0] = "[(a, b, c), (d, e, f), (x, y, z)]"`

I want to be able to read in that particular column as a `list` of `tuples`, where each element in the tuple is a string, like so:

`csv["tuplist"][0] = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('x', 'y', 'z')]`

When I read the file with `pd.read_csv()`, the type of each of these observations is `<str>`. When I used `list()` on the observations, the program returns a list of each individual character in the observation. Similarly, `csv["tuplist"][0].to_list()` does not work either.

How can I read this in as a list of tuples?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert any string that looks like a Python constant to a Python object.

Comment: You could turn it into valid `json` - use `re` to replace parens with square brackets and add quotes around each word - and then use `json.loads()`.  Note that will give you a list of lists, not a list of tuples.